# Simple math but its not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table where users can enter a part number, part price and quantity. It then multiple's the price and the quantity to get you a total. I got this part up and running.

Now i have to get the taxes on the part and then a grand total but this is what im getting:

```
function calculateit() {
    var myBox1 = $( 'input[name=tax2]:checked' ).val(); //taxes value
    var myBox2 = document.getElementById('partstotalvalue').value; //parts total value
    var result = document.getElementById('partstax'); // input field for the total of taxes * parts
    var myResult = myBox1 * myBox2; //result = taxes * parts total
    result.value = myResult; // display the results

    var result2 = document.getElementById('partstotalwithtax');  // inputp field for taxes + total value
    var totalResult = myResult + myBox2; // totalresult = taxes on part + the parts total
    result2.value = totalResult; // display the results
}
```

[image: screenshot]

Here's the fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/jdarville/hxqev0be/

Comment: Looks like you are trying to add strings instead of numbers.

Comment: FYI, when you read values from DOM, they are read as string and not numbers. You will have to manually parse it to number using `parseFloat` or `parseInt`. Also, `+` operator is also a concatination operator for string

Comment: Can you give me a fiddle ??

Comment: @AshokMandal: The code is right there. Why can't you make one?

Comment: @squint Too lazy to do that :D :P

Comment: Be careful when voting to close: `parseInt` isn't the right solution for a floating point number.

Comment: @DenysSéguret - That's already addressed in both dupe targets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem with + operator and variable types.

In your case you try to add string like this

```
var a = "1" + "2"; <- 12
```

What you need is to use ParseFloat and then do math

```
var a = parseFloat("2") + parseFloat("2.14") <- 4.14
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [unary `+` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_()) for casting to Number.

```
var myBox1 = +$( 'input[name=tax2]:checked' ).val(); //taxes value
var myBox2 = +document.getElementById('partstotalvalue').value; //parts total
```

Comment: You should not answer a question which is an obvious duplicate.

Comment: Why are you hating?

Comment: @JCD - no hate here.  just stating the facts.

Comment: @JCD: Apparently you've never experienced real hate. If you had, you'd never use that word so casually.